# Need to run a command if the jenkins build stuck

Tags: jenkins

In the Jenkins "Abort the build if it's stuck" feature, if a time out happens I want to run a powershell command, instead of aborting or failing the build. Is it possible to accomplish this?

Comment: are you using freestyle job or pipeline?

Comment: @DashrathMundkar I'm using freestyle job.

Answer (score 1):

under system configuration-> configure system, found below option:
[image]

once enabled this option, "perform build step option" will be available under "time-out action" where we can execute any script or cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could set a "Time-out variable" in the "Abort the build..." menu. Then run a post-build script using the PostBuildScript plugin that checks that env var and takes action accordingly. Haven't tried it.

Comment: Tried with Time-out variable,  it always holds the value given at "Timeout seconds" field. Expected it will be a boolean if timeout happens.